# Graphics Issue Installing Kali Linux from Live Boot

Tags: graphics-card, multi-boot, troubleshooting, kali-linux, liveusb

I'm trying to set up a dual boot windows/kali linux system. I'm able to live boot into Kali without much trouble, and have done all the necessary partitioning. Now that I've done that, I need to actually install Kali. This is where the problem is. Whenever entering one of the "Install" options from the Kali boot menu, I get a screen with what looks like a garbled table. I've waited on this screen for a while, and it never moved forward. Based on my research, I think I have a problem with my graphics driver.

I have a Lenovo computer which formerly ran Windows 8, but is currently running Windows 10. The BIOS is still a windows 8 BIOS, if that's relevant to my question. I have approximately 450 gigabytes of storage, 50 gigabites of which I've partitioned as "free space" where I hope to install my Kali system. I have 4 gigabytes of RAM. The USB disk I'm installing from has 4 gigabytes of space.

I would appreciate any help you could give me, as well as detailed instructions. While I'm experienced in Linux, I haven't worked much with troublesome installations before.

Thank you

Comment: You may need `nomodeset` to boot the live session, install and then also in the first boot of the installed system until you install the recommended proprietary graphics drivers.

Comment: Sorry, this may be a dumb question, but how do I install from a live session?

Comment: Kali can runs a live session, without installing, I suppose. If not then there's the install option right away in the first menu. Add `nomodeset` to that entry.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not quite sure how to use nomodeset, but I'm sure I'll be able to find it on google

Comment: https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/46846/what-does-nomodeset-do/

Answer (score 0):

Check the BIOS settings. Certain BIOS settings may need to be disabled to allow Linux installation and dual boot.  I suspect that the BIOS/UEFI POST during startup is prohibiting the boot because of default security settings.

Quick Option: Disable any - Fastboot, IRRT (intel rapid restore technology), Secure Boot type of options which vary by manufacture.  Restart,retry install. Also, you may need to press a manufacture specific key during power on to get into boot options menu to select between OS.

SATA configuration may also be an issue for dual boot or mutiple OS partitions.

If not successful and/or you do not want to interfere with UEFI settings the following link provides further steps for troubleshooting at linux.com

[https://www.linux.com/learn/how-install-linux-windows-machine-uefi-secure-boot]

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering. In Bios, sata controller mode is AHCI, Secure boot is disabled, boot mode is uefi, and usb boot is enabled. One weird change - before, i could see my usb in the boot order, but couldn't change the order (edits wouldn't stick after exiting bios and reentering it, yes I made sure I saved). Now, I entered Bios using the lenovo recovery button, because my keys are messed up. Before, i was using windiws advanced reboot. My usb is no longer visible and instead Lenovo recovery is in the boot order

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem of scrambled screen in installing kali through installer and graphical mode. i am using hp elitebook 820 g1
the problem was in my boot setting . before i had selected uefi mode(without csm). i had to change that to uefi(with csm). then i worked.

Go to Advance setting -> Boot Options -> either legacy or uefi (with csm).

better disable secure boot options. you might run into invalid signature issues.

Answer (score 0):

For Lenovo machines, you have to set to Legacy mode in BIOS.The only problem with this is that you can't dual boot a Win10 installation after this as Win10 is typically UEFI. It's not possible to do in Win11 since Win11 cannot boot in legacy mode. Not sure why, but the Kali installer uses a video driver that is incompatible with Lenovo's and most HPs as well as Toshiba (laptops, that is).

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, I looked on my Bios and I had 2 options to boot, one just said the name of my usb and the other one said the name and “UEFI”, I changed the boot to UEFI and it worked

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).